# Error -1073741515 when executing C++ from PHP

Tags: php, c++, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to execute a C++ executable from php in Windows Server 2012 R2. The php code that I have is:

```
<?php
$return = -1;
$file = 'helloworld.exe';
if (!file_exists($file)) echo 'File does not exists';
exec($file, $out, $return);
if($return == 0) print_r($out);
else echo "Return value: $return\n";
?>
```

When I try to execute it, I get

```
Return value: -1073741515
```

I am compiling the code with MinGW and when I run it from the command line it works. I've been doing some research and the only answer I could find is that my application is missing DLLs, but I couldn't find any actual solution to the problem. I don't have much experience in this field and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Remove stuff from `helloworld.exe` until it works. Analyse the removal step which made the difference.

Comment: @ChristianHackl b.bb.b.bb.. but that means doing work!

Comment: When you convert the error code -1073741515 to hex, you get 0xC0000135, which is "The Application failed to initialize properly."  This can have a variety of causes, including missing DLLs.  Download Depends.exe from Microsoft to see if you're missing some DLLs.  Alternatively, try running something like Calc.exe instead of your program to see if that starts up.